# Select MAX(value) from Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-table-storage

How can I extract the MAX(value) from Table Storage? 
For instance, what is the equivalent of

```
select MAX(Timestamp) FROM DailyUsers
```

(but DailyUsers is an Azure Table Storage instead of a SQL table)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the highest value in Azure Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45620116/how-to-get-the-highest-value-in-azure-table)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using c# code, you can follow the steps below:

1.Create a .net framework console project, and install the [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) nuget package, version 9.3.3.

2.Define an [entity class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/tutorial-develop-table-dotnet?toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json#define-the-entity) for your table storage. The code like below, and it's just a sample, you can modify it to meet your need:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public CustomerEntity()
        {
        }

        public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
        {
            PartitionKey = lastName;
            RowKey = firstName;
        }

        public string FirstProperty { get; set; }
        public string SecondProperty { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3.Then in the program.cs, write the code below. And to get the max date record, you can use this line of code: `OrderByDescending(r=>r.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault()`.

Sample code in program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string connstr = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;xxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net";
            var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connstr);
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("your_table_name");

            TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>();

            //if you want to get the max date value from a specified PartitionKey, you can uncomment the following code.
            //string myfilter = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "r1");
            //query.FilterString = myfilter;

            var items = table.ExecuteQuery(query).OrderByDescending(r=>r.Timestamp).FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine(items.PartitionKey+","+items.RowKey+","+items.Timestamp);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Please feel free to let me know if you have more concerns.

Comment: Please note that the code above will download the whole table to the client before sorting, which may be extremely slow and potentially lead to OutOfMemory if your table is big.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft, yes, it's client side orderby, do you know how to do the server-side orderby?

Comment: Even if specifying a partition key (uncommenting the line you mentioned), it would still have to work through the entire partition.

Comment: @Ivan Yang, I don't think it's possible to do server-side orderby.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't think this answers my question. 
`RowKey ge '20170805'` can be used to query RowKeys greater or equal to 20170805. 

I simply wanted to know if there is a query, not a c# project because the query needs to be put into json file (azure datafactory pipeline json).

Comment: @younghak, there is no guarantee for that. It just lists all the qualified data, but not has something like select(max).